# Clone Mercurial repository into public_html

Tags: mercurial, clone

I want to clone my Mercurial repository into my /public_html folder on my web server. My Mercurial project looks like this...

```
- /ProjectName
    - /public
    - /application
    - /config
    - /library
```

What I want is to just get the contents of "ProjectName" into my /public_html folder. Unfortunately, cloning the repository includes "ProjectName" and all of the subfolders are in there.

Any idea how to accomplish this without a symbolic link?

Comment: `hg clone http://repo/address .`   ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to put it out there, you probably don't want a full clone in your `public_html` unless you really want every version that ever was out there on the web.  There's nothing inherently wrong with that, but since you'll have a `.hg` in `public_html` people will even be able to clone your repository from it.

Instead consider using the `hg archive` command which exports all the files as they exist at a specific revision and places them wherever you want.

For example:

```
cd your_clone
hg archive --rev release /public_html
```

That takes the code pointed to by the `release` label (which could be a tag, bookmark, or branch head) and puts the files, but not a full-history clone, in /public_html.

Comment: That's a pretty cool solution. So I just clone the repo elsewhere on my server, then run that archive command anytime that I need to update the production files?

Comment: archive won't remove removed files, so to be absolutely sure you've got only the latest files you'd usually delete the contents of public_html and then run that command, but just running it atop the existing dir would pretty much work too.  If you wanted near-zero downtime you'd do archive to public_html_new, and then use 'mv' to swap that in instead of the old public_html dir. That would all script very neatly.

Answer (score 1):

I actually found an easy way to do this.

```
hg clone https://me@bitbucket.org/me/ProjectName "/home/website/public_html"
```

public_html has to be empty to clone the repository into it, so I moved everything out, cloned the repo, then moved the pre-existing files and folder back.

Comment: the drawback here is that you clone everything every time.  Better to do it once and then `push` or `pull` subsequently.

Comment: I just did that once to clone the repository. I use pull to get the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple step that you can follow:

```
cd /public_html
hg init .
hg pull ../pathto/ProjectName/
```

This will pull all the files and folders under `ProjectName` in `public_html` without creating `/public_html/ProjectName`.

But it will still copy all the resources that are in the mercurial repository (Files and Folders) into your directory.

Comment: Also it worth mentioning that in comparison to `clone` - this approach won't add `default` repository to `.hg/hgrc`

Comment: If you do this, you must really also take care to configure your webserver to deny access to the .hg/ folder, or anyone will be able to clone your website’s repository.